# BabylonJS Dynamically generated Animation not playing

Tags: javascript, animation, babylonjs

I’m developing a custom **AnimationSequencer** Class that, once provided with a group of keyframes, is able to dynamically generate an [Animation](https://doc.babylonjs.com/typedoc/classes/BABYLON.Animation) instance for each keyframe group, append these animations to an an [AnimationGroup](https://doc.babylonjs.com/typedoc/classes/BABYLON.AnimationGroup) and finally play the animation group on a call to the “playAll()” method. Here is the playground: https://playground.babylonjs.com/#7QN6ZM#54 On running the application, **if you navigate the the developer tools, console window you will note the following error trace;** its seems there is an issue with passing the Babylon scene to a JS class and then attempting to play animation from within the context of a JS class.
[image: Console Error StackTrace]

Curiously, as noted in the playground, everything works as expected when I attempt the process directly, (i.e non-dynamically and without use of the custom AnimationSequencer class) from a first class function.

Comment: The image of error is a bit misleading because it's not directly related to the ```_isDirty```. I think your issue here is the way you're handling vectors in ```AnimationSequencer```. Are you using **Vector3** to create vectors in your```AnimationSequencer``` class?

Comment: Of course, I've included a link to the playground.

Comment: Does no one have any ideas on this. Guess there is no BabylonJS expertise on  SO. This is the second BabylonJS question I've posted that has received no response.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've found the source of the error. It was an oversight on my part; where an animation has been declared to update the **position** attribute then the data type must be also specified as a Vector3:

```
 let meshPositionAnim = new BABYLON.Animation(
    meshAnimSequence.objectId+"MeshPositionAnimation",
    "position",
    this.defaultFPS,
    BABYLON.Animation.ANIMATIONTYPE_VECTOR3,   //Must be ANIMATIONTYPE_VECTOR3
    BABYLON.Animation.ANIMATIONLOOPMODE_CONSTANT,
    true
    );
```

I had been erroneously using **BABYLON.Animation.ANIMATIONTYPE_FLOAT** before now as I had been animating each axis independently prior, using position.x,position.y and position.z respectively (which are float values), rather than just position.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that the error might be related to the `ObjAnimationSequence` class and the way you're setting the `positionKeys` and `rotationKeys` for the `boxAnimationSequence`.

In your `boxAnimationSequence`, you're setting the `rotationKeys` as below;

```
const boxRotKeys=[
   { frame: 0,  value: new BABYLON.Vector3(0,0,0) },
   { frame: 120, value: new BABYLON.Vector3(0, 0, 0) }, 
   { frame: 180, value: new BABYLON.Vector3(0, Math.PI*2, 0) },
   { frame: 240, value: new BABYLON.Vector3(0, 0, 0) },
   { frame: 300, value: new BABYLON.Vector3(0, 0, 0) },
];
boxAnimationSequence.rotationKeys = boxRotKeys;
```

The `value` for each keyframe is a `BABYLON.Vector3` object, but when you're setting the `positionKeys` for the `boxAnimationSequence`, you're directly assigning `box.position`, which is a `BABYLON.Vector3` , to the `value` field of each keyframe;

```
const boxPosKeys=[
   { frame: 0, value: box.position },
   { frame: 120, value: new BABYLON.Vector3(20, 0, 20) },
   { frame: 180, value: new BABYLON.Vector3(40, 0, -20) },
   { frame: 240, value: new BABYLON.Vector3(20, 0, 20) },
   { frame: 300, value: new BABYLON.Vector3(10, 5, 10) },
];
```

This could cause issues if `box.position` is not properly initialized or if it's being modified elsewhere in your code. It's possible that `box.position` is being converted to a string at some point, which would cause the error you're seeing when Babylon.js tries to create the `_isDirty` property on it.

This approach may help you to fix the error. First you need to do is to create a new `BABYLON.Vector3` object for each keyframe in `boxPosKeys`, like you're doing in `boxRotKeys` to ensure that each keyframe has its own unique `BABYLON.Vector3` object, and which should prevent it from being modified elsewhere in your code.

`boxPosKeys` code same as `boxRotKeys`;

```
const boxPosKeys=[
   { frame: 0, value: new BABYLON.Vector3(box.position.x, box.position.y, box.position.z) },
   { frame: 120, value: new BABYLON.Vector3(20, 0, 20) },
   { frame: 180, value: new BABYLON.Vector3(40, 0, -20) },
   { frame: 240, value: new BABYLON.Vector3(20, 0, 20) },
   { frame: 300, value: new BABYLON.Vector3(10, 5, 10) },
];
```

If the above code doesn't fix the error, you might need to do some debugging to find out where the string is being created. You could `console.log()` the type and value of `box.position` and each keyframe's value field. This should help you identify where the string is coming from.

Comment: Thanks for your response but the error occurs whether I directly set the first frame to a Vector3 or not. In fact, before now I've completely commented out the boxPosKeys array and the same error results. Curiously, in safari the error is a little different. It occurs at the same line but the error states the property is readonly and thus cannot be updated. It's very strange!!

Comment: I've found the source of the error now @Keyboard Corporation it wasn't a problem with the Vectors themselves but rather how the associated Animation constructor was being called. I was specifying a property incorrectly. I'll post my answer in case any other members of the SO community run across this error.